# Pointwise Integral of Sequence of function

Tags: calculus, integration

For every $n \in \mathbb{N}$,
$$
f_n(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{nx}{2n-1} \quad &, x \in [0, \frac{2n-1}{n}]\\
1 \quad &, x\in [\frac{2n-1}{n}, 2]
\end{cases}
$$
I asked to determine where the $\int_1^2 f_n(x) dx$ converges to as $n \to \infty$.

My attempt:
$\int_0^{2} = \int_0^{\frac{2n-1}{2}} \frac{nx}{2n-1} dx + \int_\frac{2n-1}{n}^2 dx $. But the lower bound asked to be 1. Can I just take $n = 1$ to count $\int_0^1 f_1(x)  = \int_0^{1} x dx = \frac{1}{2}$.

So,
$ \int_0^2 f_n(x) dx = \int_0^{\frac{2n-1}{2}} \frac{nx}{2n-1} dx + \int_\frac{2n-1}{n}^2 dx  - \frac{1}{2}$.
Please provide me an explanation, I think what I did here was wrong. :(

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I've added some, please check them out.

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Just evaluate the integral after splitting the interval for ANY $n\geq 1$.  We have that
$$\int_1^{2} f_n(x)\,dx= \int_1^{\frac{2n-1}{n}} \frac{nx}{2n-1}\, dx + \int_\frac{2n-1}{n}^2 1\,dx\\=\frac{n}{2n-1} \left[\frac{x^2}{2}\right]_1^{\frac{2n-1}{n}}+\left[x\right]_{\frac{2n-1}{n}}^2.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Why it became $n\geq1$? After taking the limit n approaches $\infty$, I get 4. Am I right?

Comment: $n$ is a positive integer. No your limit is not correct. Please revise your work.